# What does pygame require to play movie files?

Tags: python, pygame

I have a video file, called intro.mpg that plays a 2 minute intro. It's properties are as follows:

```
Length: 02:23
Frame Width: 800
Frame Height: 600
Data Rate: 18500 kbps
Total Bitrate: 18884 kbps
Frame Rate: 50 fps

Bit Rate: 384 kbps
Channels 2 (stereo)
Audio Sample Rate: 44 kHz
```

Does pygame require a certain type of video file with certain properties, or is it my code:

```
import sys
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

mov_name = "resources\\video\\intro.mpg"

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
video = pygame.movie.Movie(mov_name)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(video.get_size())
video.play()

while video.get_busy():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

'Cause this is all I get:
[image]

Comment: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/movie.html has instructions on how to ensure your file is actually in the proper video format.

Answer (score 1):

You event loop is not sleeping for some time. So computer is running as fast as it can.Your code is using too much cpu. And there is not enough cpu time to play the movie.

Solution:
Try this code:

```
import sys
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
mov_name = "path_to_file"

clock=pygame.time.Clock()

####screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
video = pygame.movie.Movie(mov_name)
w,h=video.get_size()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w,h))
video.set_display(screen,(0,0,w,h))
video.play()

while True:
    event=pygame.event.wait()
    if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```